# Ruby Slice Array from other array

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am working on some specs for my Rails app that involve re-ordering Models in the database.

Since the Model IDs are not known ahead of time, I don't want to hard-code the "List of Model IDs should be [1,2,3]", so I simply collect them in an array as I create them, e.g.

```
(1..3).each
  ids << Model.create().id

Model.find(:all, order: position).should == ids
```

Anyway, I want to test my reorder logic that takes a list of ordered IDs:

```
Model.reorder( [3,1,2] ) # will change position in db
```

to keep things DRY I just do:

```
reordered_ids = [ids[3], ids[1], ids[2]]
Model.reorder( reordered_ids )

Model.find(...).should == reordered_ids
```

I was curious if there's a more elegant way to doing

```
reordered_ids = [ids[3], ids[1], ids[2]]
```

This works but doesn't seem better:

```
[3,1,2].collect{|i| ids[i] }
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> reordered_ids = [ids[3], ids[1], ids[2]]

```
reordered_ids = ids.values_at(3, 1, 2)
```

> (1..3).each   ids << Model.create().id

```
ids = 3.times.map { Model.create.id }
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is not exactly what you asked, but probably what you need.

How about not deciding the re-order yourself and doing a shuffle, like

```
reordered_ids = ids.shuffle
```

Update:
After correctly pointed by the author's comment, that there is a low priority that shuffle would be unsorted, and he wants it to be explicit, I think we can simply reverse the order in that case to make it explicit. e.g.

```
reordered_ids = ids.reverse
```

Comment: There's some low order probability that the shuffled array will be sorted, therefore not testing anything. I think for a spec it ought to be explicit